# auto update apk on kitkat error "There was a problem parsing the package"

Tags: android, android-studio

Im trying to make a "**auto update apk**" code that download a new apk with Download Manager and open it once the download is completed

on **KITKAT emulator** . When I try to launch the intent logcat doesn't show any error but I receive following message on my emulator :

> There was a problem parsing the package.

But if I open the new apk directly from the download folder it works and updates .

**Here is the method I use to download the apk ( the download code works good ):**

```
private long downloadID ;

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 20){
                Log.i("update_statut", "KitKat and bellow");
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(apkurl));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
                final String filename= URLUtil.guessFileName(apkurl, null, null);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), filename);
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                downloadID = dm.enqueue(request);
                registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete,new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
            }
```

**I am using a BroadcastReceiver to open the app when download is completed**

```
private BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        if (downloadID == id) {
            Log.i("update_statut", "Download Completed");;
            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"new-apk.apk");
            String ext = newFile.getName().substring(newFile.getName().lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
            String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile), type);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
};
```

**Permissions :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Gradle:**

> compileSdkVersion 27 minSdkVersion 16 targetSdkVersion 27

Answer (score 0):

I think you provide wrong apk file path or wrong url cause malformed apk file downloaded.

```
File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "new-apk.apk");
```

instead

```
File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "new-apk.apk");
```

(Please verify that your apk is downloaded, check file size also)

You can write less code by using `Blankj/AndroidUtilCode` library on Github. I will handle complete install process

```
AppUtils.installApp(APK_FILE_PATH)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , but the new path didnt work as well 
PS : the url and apk is ok because Im using other method for the other Build.version and they all work good except Kitkat